# How to create HTML kind pop up message box

Tags: html

When click on Submit Feedback .It should be open HTML kind pop up message box. Where I can add my comments.
............

```
<apex:page standardController="Feedback__c" extensions="CommunityFeedBackController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" >
 <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Feedback Form" rendered="{!Hide}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Feedback__c.Description__c}" style="height:180px;width:300px"/>
       <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!Save}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="window.close()"/>
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!Show}">
   <center> Your feedback has been successfully submitted.
            Thank you for leaving feedback. 
            Your contribution is valued and appreciated. </center>
    <center>
       <apex:commandButton value="Ok" onclick="window.close()"/>
    </center>
  </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>

.............

</body>
</html>
<!---<html>
    <body>
        <div class="ftr-cr">
            <div id="first-time-btns" class="overlay-button">

                <a href="/apex/CommunityFeedbackForm" style="color: #FFFFFF" target="popup" onclick='window.open("/apex/CommunityFeedbackForm", "MsgWindow", "width=400, height=400")'>
                Submit Feedback
                </a>

               <img id="ft-never" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Wirestone,'Images/misc/Dont_Show_Button.png')}" />
                <img id="ft-next" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Wirestone,'Images/misc/Close_Button.png')}" />
             </div>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>--->
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `alert` :

```
<a href="/apex/CommunityFeedbackForm" style="color: #FFFFFF" target="popup" onclick='alert('Your feedback has been successfully submitted. Thank you for leaving feedback. Your contribution is valued and appreciated.')>
Submit Feedback
</a>
```